# Replacing an unknown number in Pandas data frame with previous number

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have some data frames I am trying to upload to a database. They are lists of values but some of the columns have the string 'null' in them and so this is causing errors.

so I would like to use a function to remove these 'null' strings and am trying to use replace to back fill them below:

```
df.replace("null", method = bfill)
```

but it is giving me the error message:

```
ParserError: Error tokenizing data. C error: Expected 1 fields in line 4, saw 2
```

I have also tried putting "bfill" instead and it just replaced "null" with the string "bfill."

Any help appreciated.

Thanks.

Sorry should have provided an example:

```
1     6     11
2     7     12
null  null  null
4     9     14
5     10    15
```

Comment: Can you add some data sample (4-5 rows) of your data?

Comment: And what are parameters of `read_csv` if use it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you need [`replace`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.replace.html) strings `null` to `NaN`s and then call `bfill` ([`fillna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.fillna.html) with `method='bfill'`) and if some `NaN`s in the end of data add `ffill` for forward filling:

```
df = df.replace("null",np.nan).bfill().ffill()
```

But your error is obviously in [`read_csv`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_csv.html) function, check line 4 - parser need only one value and for some reason there are 2 values.

**Sample**:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A':['k','null','n','null','null','m'],
                   'B':['t','null','null','f','null','s'],
                   'C':['r','t','null','s','null','null']})

print (df)
      A     B     C
0     k     t     r
1  null  null     t
2     n  null  null
3  null     f     s
4  null  null  null
5     m     s  null
```

---

```
print (df.replace("null",np.nan))
     A    B    C
0    k    t    r
1  NaN  NaN    t
2    n  NaN  NaN
3  NaN    f    s
4  NaN  NaN  NaN
5    m    s  NaN
df1 = df.replace("null",np.nan).bfill()
print (df1)
   A  B    C
0  k  t    r
1  n  f    t
2  n  f    s
3  m  f    s
4  m  s  NaN
5  m  s  NaN

#if some `NaN`s in last row is necessary `ffill`
df2 = df.replace("null",np.nan).bfill().ffill()
print (df2)
   A  B  C
0  k  t  r
1  n  f  t
2  n  f  s
3  m  f  s
4  m  s  s
5  m  s  s
```

Comment: Thanks Jezrael that worked. Although I should have provided an example like other comments suggested because the values were floats.

Comment: Glad can help! Yes, samples are helpful ;)

Answer (score 1):

Borrowing @jezrael's sample data set:

```
In [11]: df[df.ne('null')].bfill().ffill()
Out[11]:
   A  B  C
0  k  t  r
1  n  f  t
2  n  f  s
3  m  f  s
4  m  s  s
5  m  s  s
```